# How to secure things, such as Firebase Database calls in your APK?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Since APKs can be decompiled, changed, and recompiled, what is preventing a user from decompiling an example APK with code such as:

```
onClick() {
    // Add a new "room" to the /rooms/ node
    val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/rooms").push()
}
```

And changing it to:

```
onClick() {
    // Add a new "room" to the /rooms/ node
    for (x in 1..10000)
        val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/rooms").push()
}
```

Recompile, and well, wreak some havoc? The decompiled APK will still have access to the google-services json file. I assume there must be some way to prevent this type of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping someone from doing this.

What you're supposed to do is either:

- Implement [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) that check on the backend which operations the user is supposed to actually be able to do from the client.
- Implement a backend endpoint to be invoked by the client that checks to see if the user should be able to perform the operation, then performs it.

In both cases, you should be using Firebase Auth to authenticate the user, so that your backend code or rules can authorize each specific action they take.

Comment: But this is an operation the client can perform. In this example, creating a room. Or, maybe sending a single message. There would be permitted via Firebase DB's security rules, as long as the user is logged in via auth. What can't be specified (I think?) is to prevent the type of spamming provided in the example above.

Comment: Try doing a search for "firebase realtime database rules rate limit" for SO results.  If you have a specific question about rules you've written that don't work the way you expect, post it separately and explain what's wrong.

Comment: Kinda feel like we're getting lost in the weeds here. I'm just providing an example of a way a recompiled APK can abuse Firebase Database commands, asking if, hypothetically speaking - how can this type of behavior be prevented? I assume it is, else Firebase Database is useless. Example 2) In my APK I have a batch command to atomically update 2 tables at once. A recompiled APK can remove one of these commands, thus creating instability in the data on the database backend. What prevents a user from doing this?

Comment: As my answer states, there is nothing stopping anyone from trying this.  You'll have to write code to implement whatever limits you want to place on access from the internet at large.  There is not a simple configuration that stops this.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Signed Apk with obfuscation enabled with release build. Obfuscation modifies your code in such a way that reverse-engineering becomes quite impossible to understand. It will also shrink and optimize your code which will reduce your app size. In android, it's too easy to use obfuscation. Like this, in your **app-level** gradle file:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You may need to skip some files or classes or methods etc. to obfuscate. The *'proguard-rules.pro'* file will help you to do so.
For more you can see this documentation: *https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code*

Comment: obfuscation makes the process harder, but it doesn't make it _impossible_  for someone to get access to your data